# Cancel jqGrid delete event

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which is using the inbuilt delete function to call a delete action in my controller.

I would like to cancel the delete event and stop my action being called in the controller if a validation function returns false.

I have tried returning false in `onClickSubmit`, however my action is still called.

Below is the `formatOptions` code for my jqGrid. The `onClickSubmit` function is called before the controller action is invoked.

```js
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    editbutton: false,
    editformbutton: false,
    delOptions: {
        url: $(URL).val(),
        caption: 'Delete',
        width: 'auto',
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete these record(s)?',
        bSubmit: "Delete",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        mtype: 'POST',

        onclickSubmit: function (response, postdata, formid) {

            return false;


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `beforeSubmit` callback instead of `onclickSubmit` if you need to cancel deleting. The callback `beforeSubmit` should return array with two elements. The first element should be Boolean `true` or `false`, where `false` means stop of deleting. The second element should be the string with the error description. It should exist if the first element is `false`. For example,

```js
formatoptions: {
    keys: true,
    editbutton: false,
    editformbutton: false,
    delOptions: {
        url: $(URL).val(),
        caption: 'Delete',
        width: 'auto',
        msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete these record(s)?',
        bSubmit: "Delete",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        mtype: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: function (postdata) {
            if (/* come test of postdata*/) {
                return [false, "One can't delete the row"];
            }
            return [true]; // allow to delete
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, saved me a lot of time. Thanks!